# Can't run any file named install.php on localhost due to apache's access_compat

Tags: apache, localhost

I'm getting a weird problem here.
I have at least 30 localhost WordPress installs made before and every one of them went fine.
Now (after re-installing Win7 and XAMPP) I can't access ANY install.php file (whether it's WPs own, a dummy empty one, etc). Also, it doesn't matter where it's located (wp-admin folder, a random place outside WP, htdocs root folder, etc).

This is not an antivirus or Windows firewall problem.
It seems to be coming from apache itself.
The apache error log says this

[Fri Nov 30 16:46:40.223524 2012] [access_compat:error] [pid 5876:tid 1604] [client ::1:59365] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: D:/xampp/htdocs/vmf05/wp-admin/install.php

Does anyone have a clue on this?
I've went through all the normal steps and haven't found a solution yet.

Also, if I disable the access_compat module, apache won't start.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe what the problem was!
I moved a .htaccess file that had the WP better security directives to the root of xampp's site as a backup, and forgot to move it back after.

No install.php file ANYWHERE could be accessed since it had the following:

```
<files install.php>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</files>
```

And, since the file was on the root, it was affecting the whole server.